# Why isn't this expression returning true to being positive when it is clearly positive?

Tags: equation-solving, assumptions, inequalities, expression-construction

Consider:

```
Expre10 = (B^2/C + 2 B + B^2/D + (B C)/D + (B D)/C) + 
   1 (C + D) - (A \[Beta] \[Sigma])/(B C D) (C + D);
Assuming[{A > 0, B > 0, C > 0, 
  D > 0, \[Beta] > 0, \[Sigma] > 0, (A \[Beta] \[Sigma])/(B C D) <=  
   1}, Simplify[Expre10 > 0]]
```

Returns the inequality:

B (B + C) (B + D) > A [Beta] [Sigma]

But we clearly see if `(A \[Beta] \[Sigma])/(B C D) <= 1` holds then our inequality will always be true, so why am I getting the wrong output?

Comment: Aren't $C$ and $D$ reserved Mathematica commands? I wouldn't recommend using capital letters as variable names for this very reason.

Comment: @Moo I didn't know, however I still get the same results with different letters

Comment: Look closer. The result you got is structured like `(X > Y) > 0`. To see why this is wrong, imagine doing `(2 > 1) > 0` which returns `True > 0` - this is incorrect. Your Expre10 already contains a `>` sign and your `Simplify` is adding on this extra `> 0` at the end.

Comment: I made a typo! Its still not resulting true.

Comment: `C` and `D` are protected system symbols. Best practice is to avoid single capital letters for your own variables. Recommended practice is to avoid starting your variable/function names with a captial. See https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18395/4999, point 4.

Comment: This problem persists even with `{A, B, C, D}` replaced by lower-case letters.  Nonetheless, this is not a suitable question, because it asks (in effect), why isn't Mathematica capable of doing what I think it should, which cannot be answered except by Wolfram staff.

Comment: @bbgodfrey My question was answered hence it was a suitable question so I don't see a problem here. Please look below at the answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Simplify` is at root an expression tree minimizer, equipped with some algebraic and logical transformations. As such, it may have the transformations needed to reach your goal, but its main goal is to apply transformations that result in smaller expression trees. It is also possible that it may not try the transformation needed to get to your goal. Functions  whose purpose is to solve algebraic systems, such as `Reduce`, are generally more robust.  They tend not to mind if all the cases to consider get quite complicated.  Whereas `Simplify` is like a first-year university student who feels it's time to give up when things get complicated, `Reduce` is like a graduate student determined to impress their professor.

```
Expre10 = (B^2/C + 2 B + B^2/D + (B C)/D + (B D)/C) + 
     1 (C + D) - (A β σ)/(B C D) (C + D) /. C -> c /. 
   D -> d;
Assuming[{A > 0, B > 0, c > 0, 
   d > 0, β > 0, σ > 0,
   (A β σ)/(B c d) <= 1}, 
 Reduce[$Assumptions \[Implies] Expre10 > 0, {}, Reals]]

(*  True  *)
```

Specifying the domain `Reals` is key here, too.